# Cálculo do menor número divisível dando loop infinito em C

Tags: c, loop, for

Eu fiz um programa em C para resolver o seguinte exercício:

[image: Exercício]

Código:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

int num = 0;
int count = 20;
int contaDivisores = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= 20; j++){
        //Esse loop checa se o numero atual e divisivel por todos os numeros de 1 a 20
        if(i % j == 0){
            contaDivisores++;//Se for divisivel, aumenta o contador de divisores
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    if(contaDivisores == 20){
        num = count;/*Se o numero acima for divisivel por todos
         os numeros, significa que a contagem atual é o numero desejado*/
        break;
    }else{
        count++;//Se não for, muda o numero que deverá ser checado em 
  //seguida
    }
 }

 printf("Numero:%d\n", num);//Mostra o número

 return 0;
}
```

Porém, ao executar o código, obtém-se um loop infinito:

[image: Loop Infinito]

Tentei fazer algumas mudanças no código, mas não consegui solucionar o problema. O que deve ser feito para que o loop infinito não ocorra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução bem prática (explicações nos comentários no código):

```
// Define o range de divisores:
const unsigned short MAX = 20;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    // Resultado, do tipo long, pois rapidamente estoraria
    // valor máximo de int (2147483647). 
    // O máximo de ulong é 18446744073709551615
    unsigned long int number = 0;

    // Loop infinito, pois não sabemos quantas iterações haverão
    while (1)
    {
        // Número de divisores encontrados
        unsigned short dividers = 0;

        number++;

        // Itera sobre o range de valores
        for (unsigned short i = 1; i <= MAX; i++)
        {
            // O valor é um divisor?
            if (number % i == 0) {
                // Se sim, incrementa o número de divisores
                dividers++;
            } else {
                // Se não, vai para o próximo número
                break;
            }
        }

        // Foram encontrados todos os divisores?
        if (dividers == MAX) {
            // Sim, exibe o valor e encerra o loop infinito
            printf("Numero:%d\n", number);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Rodando para 10 valores, o resultado é `2520`, como esperado. Para 20 valores, o resultado é `232792560`.

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/HRQO/0) ou [aqui](https://ideone.com/rftmdM).

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Cara eu não entendi bem a pergunta, mas o loop se dá porque a sua variavel cont sempre será maior que i, então te aconselho usar "while" e sem uma variavel, poem o numero 20 como fizeste no segundo "for".